# JScript error when implementing kendo ui editor

Tags: jquery, webforms, kendo-ui

Hey I've been messing around with this for a while now and I've run out of things to try. I've been trying to use kendo ui (web) to turn a textarea into an editor, and I'm getting this error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'ready'"

It seems like a common problem is improper/multiple referencing to jquery script(s), but I'm pretty sure I got that right at this point. Here's what I have:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link href="~/Styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
    <textarea id="txtBody" rows="10" cols="30" style="width:400px;height:100px" runat="server"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtBody").kendoEditor({
                tools: [
                    "bold", "italic", "underline", "strikethrough",
                    "justifyLeft", "justifyCenter", "justifyRight", "justifyFull",
                    "insertUnorderedList", "insertOrderedList",
                    "indent", "outdent",
                    "createLink", "unlink",
                    "subscript", "superscript",
                    "viewHtml",
                    "formatting", "fontName", "fontSize", "foreColor", "backColor" ]
                        }); });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

As you can see I'm using jquery-1.7.1 which is what is suggested for kendo ui 2.717 (the version I'm using).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not that I'm really expecting an answer now, but I did get rid of the error by removing the "~" from the path strings; however, it still doesn't work, I just end up with a textarea and no error.

Comment: Try running it in chrome or firefox with the firebug plugin installed, you'll get a more descriptive error message

Comment: I actually don't get an error since changing the path, the kendo component just doesn't work. I traced through some of the JScript though and it seems like the problem might be a null return from getElementById("txtBody"), but I don't know why that's happening.

Comment: For anyone wondering it was the runat="server". I took that out and accessed the element through the td element it was inside.

Comment: how come if you remove jquery-1.7.1.min.js  and add kendo.web.min.js

Comment: maybe replace the $(document).ready(function(){

with document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){